# Problem to convert date into string in excel

Tags: excel, date, text, excel-formula

I am facing an issue to convert a date into string in excel using TEXT and TODAY().

When I use the following formula:

```
="today is " & TEXT(TODAY(); "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

into a cell I got a value error. When I test with a different formatting:

```
="today is " & TEXT(TODAY(); "ddmmyyyy")
```

this time I got "today is dd12yyyy" instead of today is 02122022.
I would like to display according the first formatting: "today is 02/12/2022" (For December 2nd 2022).

Comment: What locale settings are you at? In other words, in your excel you may need other charaters to represent days and year. Possibly something like `tt/mm/jjjj`

Comment: @JvdV The seetings are on `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Comment: "The settings are on dd/MM/yyyy" as in when you select the numberformat of a date you get the dd/MM/yyyy? Because it would still mean that in excel you need to use your locale version where it might be different. In Belgian settings for example it's still `d/MM/jjjj` (see Control Panel -> Locate and select Change date, time, or number formats within the Clock, Language, and Region category)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you need:

```
="today is " & TEXT(TODAY(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

I have tested on mine and that works correctly.

If you copied that formula from the web then they may have the ; as their separator, something we have learnt to spot.

[image]

Comment: If that were the issue, the second attempt wouldn't have worked either, in Dutch it's also ; seperator and Excel throws an error when you use the , as seperator.